# Number of components on PCA limited by the number of samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I'm using sklearn to do PCA, I'm testing the functions with some dummy data, when I have more samples than the number of components I want to use it works just fine:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np    

features_training = np.random.rand(10,30)
components = 8
pca = PCA(n_components=int(components))
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(features_training)
```

From the code above I get a 10*8 matrix.

```
X_pca.shape
(10, 8)
```

But for the same data, if I try to keep 15 components:

```
features_training = np.random.rand(10,30)
components = 15
pca = PCA(n_components=int(components))
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(features_training)
```

I don't get a 10*15 matrix but a 10*10 one.

```
X_pca.shape
(10, 10)
```

So it seems that the number of components is limited not only by the number of features but for the number of samples. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you about how actually the PCA works. But in the Scikit-learn [documentation for PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA), it is mentioned that `actual n_components = min(n_samples, specified n_components)`